# the ways the phrase " I guess ( that ) ... " is used in today's usage ? where u think a good place to start from?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Can you English Speakers ( especially native ones) help me with getting a better idea of the ways the phrase

> " I guess ( that ) ... "

is used in today's usage  ? I mean, where u think a good place to start from ?

Comment: I guess that functions like I think that. Same idea. Only you are not 100%.

Comment: 'It seems to me...', 'I suppose...', 'maybe...' there are many ways to express tentativeness.

Comment: Actually it's a pretty unique phrase in English. Often it introduces something you didn't realize before but are voicing for the first time after coming to accept it as probably true, as in "I guess there's nothing we can do."